# How to run an animation from an XML file?

Tags: android

I have created an animation file in the animator directory of android studio. I am trying to change the colour of a button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator android:duration="500"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:propertyName="color"
android:valueTo="#333333"
android:valueFrom="@color/start_button"
/>
```

Then i tried to run the animation from my MainActivity.java, but when i click on the button to run the animation the app crashes.

```
public void btnClick(View view){
        AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.rotation);
        set.setTarget(view); // set the view you want to animate
        set.start();
    }
```

Comment: please post the error stacktrace. Thanks

Comment: i don't get an error instead, when i run it in the emulator the app simply stops working when the animation starts.

Comment: Check logs there must be some error regarding Crash . If you are having problems with animation then you should also mention what kind of animation you need . Question is incomplete right now .

Comment: i just get a message in the emulator that the app has stopped running. and there is nothing in the event log.

Comment: Where did you create animation file under `res/anim` folder?

Comment: no under res/animator

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51703161/1283715), Try `backgroundColor` instead of `color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`android:propertyName`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource)

> String. Required. The object's property to animate, referenced by its
>   name. For example you can specify "**`alpha`**" or "**`backgroundColor`**" for a
>   View object. The objectAnimator element does not expose a target
>   attribute, however, so you cannot set the object to animate in the XML
>   declaration. You have to inflate your animation XML resource by
>   calling loadAnimator() and call setTarget() to set the target object
>   that contains this property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <objectAnimator android:duration="500"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:propertyName="backgroundColor"
       android:valueTo="#333333"
       android:valueFrom="@color/start_button"
    />
</set>
```

**Inflating and run AnimatorSet**

```
AnimatorSet set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.rotation);
set.setTarget(view); // set the view you want to animate
set.start();
```

**Update**

If you set `propertyName="color"` then the target view shall have `setColor` method.

> W/PropertyValuesHolder: Method setColor() with type int not found on target class class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

In general `propertyName="someName"` then target view shall has method `setSomeName`

**Ex.** If you need to change custom view `angle` then `propertyName="angle"`
and custom target view must implement `setAngle`

Comment: @pabolo12 Please check my answer update, and don't forget to accept my answer if you feel that helped you to fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
int colorStart = v.getSolidColor();
            int colorEnd = 0xFFFF0000;
            ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v,"backgroundColor",colorStart, colorEnd);
            colorAnim.setDuration(2000);
            colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
            colorAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
            colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
            colorAnim.start();

}
```